# Plant identification for a shrub in Hampshire, UK

Tags: identification

Can anyone assist with an ID for a small tree I have growing in my front garden(Hampshire, England)?

It’s a tree with small green leaves and pink blossom.

The branches and bark appear flaky.  [image: leaves][image: Leaves and blossom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Escallonia, not sure which variety, there are a fair number of pink through to red varieties. Yours has quite large leaves compared to some; Escallonia 'Gold Ellen' has dark pink flowers with yellowish green leaves, image here https://www.classicroses.co.uk/escallonia-laevis-gold-ellen.html

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you!